# How to target elements using tumblr variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I am struggling to target specific posts in my javascript. Tumblr has own variables such as {PostID} but I can't use them in Javascript in my theme or at least I don't know how to do it.

My example:

I want to check if in a post a div's content is overflown.
If that's the case JS should adjust the CSS of just this one's post.
And then JS should move to the next post and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter through all posts, instead use `.each()`. (This is jQuery, not JS, but you have tagged your post with the 'jquery' tag so I assume you are happy to use it).

For example:

```
$('.post-selector').each(function() {
    // check for overflow
});
```

If you are using infinite scroll you will need to do the same thing in the callback.